# GetModuleInformation fails when using LoadLibraryExA(...,...,LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, code-signing

I am using `dliNotePreLoadLibrary` in my own delay loading hook to verify the code signature of a DLL to be loaded before actually loading it. In order to avoid it to execute *any* code whatsoever, I load it by means of `LoadLibraryExA(...,...,LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)` (the hook only provides the ANSI name, so that's okay) and unload it after verification so that it can be loaded as a DLL with code.

Stepping through the code in the debugger I can see that I receive a handle and that handle is `<baseaddress>+1` as expected for a "data module". However, once I attempt to pass this handle to `GetModuleFileName` inside a library function (that is also the reason why I can't pass the name, only the module handle), the function returns `0` and GetLastError gives me `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. However, the module got loaded, so it was definitely found. Also, this is in the current process, so access to the "target process" is no issue here.

So I thought why not use `VirtualQuery` to retrieve the actual base address (`MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::BaseAddress`) of the DLL I just loaded (in case the `<baseaddress>+1` is an issue), but the result remains the same: `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

Platform of the tests: Windows 7 SP1, x64 (latest patches)

Here's the code of the:

```
FARPROC WINAPI MyDliHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{
    switch(dliNotify)
    {
    case dliNotePreLoadLibrary:
        if(0 == lstrcmpiA(pdli->szDll, "DLLNAME.dll"))
        {
            HMODULE hVerifiedDll = LoadLibraryExA(pdli->szDll, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
            if(hVerifiedDll)
            {
                MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
                if(0 != VirtualQuery(hVerifiedDll, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)));
                {
                    VerifyModuleSignature((HMODULE)mbi.BaseAddress, pdli->szDll);
                }
                FreeLibrary(hVerifiedDll);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return NULL;
}
PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = MyDliHook;
```

The function `VerifyModuleSignature` calls first of all `GetModuleFileName` to retrieve the file name and it fails at that step. I verified that with the `.exe` that creates the process, the code signature verification works fine.

**Side-note:** I have verified that the `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` error comes from `GetModuleFileName` and not, for example, from the earlier call to `LoadLibraryExA`. In order to make sure I don't get a "polluted" last error code I called `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)` right before the call to `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: GetModuleFileName() cannot work for DLLs loaded with the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE option.  That option just loads a blob of bytes, the loader doesn't otherwise keep track of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you cannot retrieve the Module using GetModuleHandle when LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE is used:

> If this value is used, the system maps the file into the calling process's virtual address space as if it were a data file. Nothing is done to execute or prepare to execute the mapped file. Therefore, you cannot call functions like GetModuleFileName, GetModuleHandle or GetProcAddress with this DLL.

**Edit:** Actually Hans Passant was a bit closer to the reason than this answer. While this answer reiterates what MS states, it doesn't give a reason. The reason however, is that `GetModuleFileName` basically walks the [`LDR_MODULE`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/LDR_MODULE.html) list of the `PEB`, and that is only populated with the details when you "load code".